# Download Files from Azure Batch

Tags: c#, azure, azure-batch

I would like to download the files after the task is complete. 
How can I do it efficiently?

Unfortunately, *task.EnvironmentSettings* is null and the following code snipet does not work (see the Microsoft [instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-api-basics/)).

```
IList<environmentsetting> listEnv = task.EnvironmentSettings;

var envList = listEnv.Where(x => x.Name == "AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR").ToList();
```

also

```
var fileList = task.FilesToStage
```

trigerrs the error:
*The property FilesToStage cannot be read while the object is in the Bound state.*

Answer (score 0):

The following methods provide access to a task's files:

- [CloudTask.GetNodeFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.batch.cloudtask.getnodefile.aspx) (and GetNodeFileAsync)

You can list the files in the CloudTask's directory on its compute node with:

- [CloudTask.ListNodeFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.batch.cloudtask.listnodefiles.aspx)